# upstart - run python script in background not from root folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, upstart

I have a python script which is in some folder say `/home/pcname/Program/myScript.py`. I run it on computer startup using upstart. My python program has some mv, cp operation which it does with respect to Program folder. But when this script runs through upstart it takes / (root) as the folder and does mv cp operations with respect to that folder.

Is it possible to change this, so that program runs w.r.t Program folder and not / (root) when started with upstart?